# I tried to create a splash screen and wait for 3 seconds then go to login page but flutter throwed an error plz help me fix that?

Tags: flutter, dart, exception

i recently started flutter devolopment and i tried to create a splash screen and wait for 3 seconds then goto login page but flutter throwed an error plz help me fix that

FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey#83433]
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
Builder)

Comment: share your code to get better answer

Answer (score 0):

You should have provided more code to help solving your issue.

But by reading your console log, I saw that you have used `SetState()`, which is not necessary in this case. You should be creating a `StatelessWidget` as your SplashScreen and then use `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/<path_to_your_main_route>')` inside a `initState()` to replace your SplashScreen to your main screen.
**Try this:**

```
    `import 'dart:io';
@override
      void initState() {
    sleep(const Duration(seconds:3));
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/<path_to_your_main_route>');
      }`
```

Comment: Future<void> gotoLogin() async {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (ctx) {
        return LoginScreen();
      },
    ));

Comment: this is the code which have error i didnt used setstate in the firstplace